# Undefined method 'User message path" in Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nomethoderror

I am trying to add a link to my Posts>Index page which lets people send direct message (using Simple Private Messaging) to the creator of the Post.

Currently I have a link to /messages/new to do this, but this is not working - Iget the following error in my app when I try to access /messages/new.

I want to replace the link to /messages/new (in POSTS>INDEX file below) with something better that works. Let me know if you have any thoughts!!

```
**NoMethodError in Messages#new**

Showing /Users/fkhalid2008/loand/app/views/messages/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `user_messages_path' for #<#<Class:0x12a77f198>:0x12a76dce0>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% form_for @message, :url => user_messages_path(@user) do |f| %>
2:   <p>
3:     To:<br />
4:      <%= f.text_field :to %>
```

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: The app itself is like Gumtree.com, where Users come and create Posts (e.g. selling my car), and people respond my sending them Messages (through the Simple Pvt Messages plugin).

Thanks!

Faisal

**MESSAGES>NEW VIEW**

```
<% form_for @message, :url => user_messages_path(@user) do |f| %>
<p>
To:<br />
    <%= f.text_field :to %>
    <%= error_message_on @message, :to %>
</p>
<p>
Subject:<br />
<%= f.text_field :subject %>
<%= error_message_on @message, :subject %>
</p>
<p>
  Message<br />
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
        <%= error_message_on @message, :body %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**MESSAGE MODEL**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

is_private_message

attr_accessor :to

end
```

**ROUTES.RB**

```
Mysalary::Application.routes.draw do

resources :messages do
   collection do
     post :delete_selected
     end
   end

resources :users
resources :profiles
resources :pages
resources :posts

get "pages/home"
get "pages/about"
get "pages/legal"
get "pages/feedback"

root :to => 'posts#new'

end
```

**MESSAGES CONTROLLER**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :set_user

def index
if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
  @messages = @user.sent_messages
else
  @messages = @user.received_messages
end
end

def show
@message = Message.read_message(params[:id], current_user)
end

def new
@message = Message.new

if params[:reply_to]
  @reply_to = @user.received_messages.find(params[:reply_to])
  unless @reply_to.nil?
    @message.to = @reply_to.sender.login
    @message.subject = "Re: #{@reply_to.subject}"
    @message.body = "\n\n*Original message*\n\n #{@reply_to.body}"
  end
end
end

def create
@message = Message.new(params[:message])
@message.sender = @user
@message.recipient = User.find_by_login(params[:message][:to])

if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = "Message sent"
  redirect_to user_messages_path(@user)
else
  render :action => :new
end
end

def delete_selected
if request.post?
  if params[:delete]
    params[:delete].each { |id|
      @message = Message.find(:first, :conditions => ["messages.id = ? AND (sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?)", id, @user, @user])
      @message.mark_deleted(@user) unless @message.nil?
    }
    flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
end

private
def set_user
 @user = User.first
end
end
```

**POSTS>INDEX VIEW**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tbody>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
<td>I am a <%= post.title %> getting married in <%= post.job %> in <%= post.location %>, and looking for a <%= post.salary %>. My budget is <%= post.salary %>.</td>
<td> <button class="btn" data-toggle="button" onClick="javascript:location.href = '/messages/new';" />Contact</button></td>
<td><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.</td>
<!--/. 
<td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
-->
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you routes.rb doesn't define path `user_messages_path`, it's simple :)

If you want nested restful routes, you need something like

```
resources :users do
  resources :messages
end
```

Comment: is there any way to fix it other than nested routes..?

Comment: I used to have the nested route but it was causing a lot of other errors thats why I changed it...

Comment: I added posts>index view...thats where the /messages/new link is...i want to replace it with another link that lets users send messages to each other..

Comment: ok, try to use `messages_path(:user_id => @user)` route helper instead

Comment: I tried but it still loads up a blank webpage for /messages/new...what should I do now?

Comment: You also must to ensure that form use appropriate http method.

Comment: thanks! i still have a few other bugs in the form, which i need to fix, but your answer at least helped fix the one i had posted this question for - i.e. problem with the routes

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<% form_for @message do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: tried it, got this error undefined method `error_message_on' for #<#<Class:0x12a37a7f0>:0x12a36dff0>.

Comment: also if i do that then how do i know that the message will go to the right user...i don't think so it will then